# Church's definition of "or" in Lambda Calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

I have been working through Church's *Postulates for the foundation of logic*.  In the paper he has some four definitions that he will then use in order to formulate the later postulates.

If someone could illuminate one of these for me, I am sure I could continue with my excursion.

---

$$
V \rightarrow \lambda\mu\lambda\nu.\sim.\sim\mu .\sim\nu
$$

Then $V(\text{P}, \text{Q})$ should be read as "P or Q".

My understanding is that it gets expanded as such then,

$$
\{\{ \lambda\mu\lambda\nu.\sim.\sim\mu .\sim\nu \}\left (\text{P}\right )\}(\text{Q})
$$

Because a function of two variables become a function of one variable whose values are functions of one variable.

My question then is, how do I go forth from here?  It is probably an issue of not being able to substitute correctly.  Intuitively $\text{P}$ goes into the function to the left, but then that gets a truth value and is no longer a function.

Comment: Could you define the extension of the $\lambda$-calculus you are working with here? I don't know $\sim$.

Comment: I am not working with an extension, It is the paper in which Church describes the system. $\sim$ is Not. $\sim (\text{P})$ would be read as Not P.

Comment: I meant to say that it might be helpful to recall the system in the question because in pure $\lambda$-calculus there is nothing like $\sim$.

Comment: From A Set of Postulates for the Foundation of Logic in *Annals of Mathematics*, Second series. 33(2) 1932. pp. 346 - 399: "The symbol $\sim$ stands for a certain propositional function on one independent variable, such that, if P is a proposition, then $\sim(\text{P})$ is the negation of P and may be read, 'Not-P'"


I'm sorry that I cannot be more specific as to what extension it is, because that is the paper from which I am working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I answer the question, let me enumerate an additional definition.  I think that this inclusion would help illuminate the conclusion.

$$
(1)~~~V \rightarrow \lambda\mu\lambda\nu.\sim.\sim\mu.\sim\nu
$$
$$
(2)~~~U\rightarrow \lambda\mu\lambda\nu.\sim.\mu.\sim\nu
$$

$V$ is the function OR, $V(\text{P},\text{Q}) \equiv [\text{P}] \vee [\text{Q}]$. $U$ is the function IMPLIES, $[\text{P}] \Rightarrow [\text{Q}]$. $Q$ is the function for equivalence, $Q(\lambda x.\text{M}, \lambda x.\text{N})$ is read as $[\text{M}] \equiv_x [\text{N}]$.

If we look at the function $\neg(\text{P} \wedge \neg \text{Q})$, note that $\neg \text{X}$ and $\sim\text{X}$ are merely varying notation according to Church's definitions, we can reduce that to $\text{P} \Rightarrow \text{Q}$.
If we now look at the function $\neg (\neg\text{P}\wedge\neg\text{Q})$, we can reduce that to $(\text{P} \vee \text{Q})$.
Both of these propositional functions share form and consequence with (1) and (2) respectively.

The question is then not simply how the function $V$ is reduced in Church's $\lambda$-Calculus, it is how P and Q interact with one another in the function, since $\sim$ is a function that takes only one argument.  That argument is therefore then a conjunction of the two arguments, in (1): $(\sim\mu\wedge\sim\nu)$, and in (2): $(\mu\wedge\sim\nu)$.

> It is probably an issue of not being able to substitute correctly. Intuitively P goes into the function to the left, but then that gets a truth value and is no longer a function.

$$
\{\{\lambda\mu\lambda\nu.\sim.\sim\mu.\sim\nu\}(\text{P})\}(\text{Q})
$$
$$
\{\lambda\nu.\sim.\sim\text{P}.\sim\nu\}(\text{Q})
$$
$$
\sim[\sim\text{P}][\sim\text{Q}]
$$
$$
[\text{P}] \vee [\text{Q}]
$$

The penultimate step should perhaps be more correctly expressed as $\sim[\sim\text{P}[\sim\text{Q}]]$, but it does not lend as much understanding I think.

I've spent some time pondering this problem, and I believe that I have come to the correct conclusion.  If anyone disagrees with me, I am sure they will make themselves heard.

Comment: I think that you are right; the basic concept is "functional application" : with a multi-argument function you "apply" it to one argument at time, "reducing" progressively the number of arguments. Consider (I'll use "usual" symbols) the two-argument places function $+$("sum"); we can represent it as $+(x,y)$. Then, applying it to the value $1$ as second-argument (this is where the $\lambda$ formalism is useful, because it traces the order of applications) we get the new unary function $+(x,1)$ i.e. a function that "adds one" to its argument.

Comment: In the case of the $\lor$ truth-functional connective (i.e. a binary function), we have, after the "first application" a unary function : $\lambda x.\lnot.\lnot x.\lnot Q$ which is like $x \lor Q$. We jhave saturated the second argument-place and we are left with a one-argument function.